# How to stop bazel from relying on Python2

Tags: python, bazel

when running `bazel test` Bazel seems to default to Python 2 even when `--python-version` flag is specified

```
bazel test //... --python_version PY3
```

```
INFO: From Testing //test:py-unit-tests:
==================== Test output for //test:py-unit-tests:
/usr/bin/env: 'python': No such file or directory
```

This is my BUILD file

```
py_test(
    name = "py-unit-tests",
    srcs = glob(["unit/**/*.py"]),
    deps = [
    ],
    main = "unit/unit_test_runner.py",
    timeout = "short",
)
```

And the test file

```
import sys
import unittest


class TestGeneration(unittest.TestCase):
    def test_base(self):
        pass
    def test_urdf(self):
        self.assertEqual("hello", 'test')


if __name__ == '__main__':
    unittest.main()
```

Bazel version: 3.3.1

---

Other notable things:

1. My system has both py2 and py3 installed
2. Py3 is located at `/usr/bin/python3`
3. Py2 is located at  `/usr/bin/python2`

There is no `/usr/bin/python`

Comment: Which version of Bazel are you using?
Python 3 should be the default (since Bazel 0.25 I think - https://blog.bazel.build/2019/05/01/bazel-0.25.html).

Comment: Yeah I know. That's what is really confusing. I'm using 3.3.1. Updated the question.

Comment: it might default to python3 is /usr/env/python exists and points to py3, but if only /usr/env/python3 exists it doesn't do it as far as I can tell

Comment: Found the issue here but the solution without a symlink is unknown currently https://github.com/bazelbuild/bazel/issues/11554

Answer (score 4):

As described in https://github.com/bazelbuild/bazel/issues/11554, the issue is that your Bazel python stub has a `#!/usr/bin/env python` shebang. If `python` is not on the PATH like in your case, the stub will fail.

Previously the only solution would be to add a symlink from `python` to `python3`, e.g. by installing

```
sudo apt install python-is-python3
```

However since https://github.com/bazelbuild/bazel/commit/763dd0ce6e1644bf895231432f616427a11d385a has landed that stub shebang has become configurable. You can now define your own `py_runtime` (https://docs.bazel.build/versions/main/be/python.html#py_runtime)

Alternatively, since https://github.com/bazelbuild/bazel/commit/2945ef5072f659878dfd88b421c7b80aa4fb6c80 the default shebang has also become `#!/usr/bin/env python3`

These two commits are only available from Bazel 5.0.0 though, so for now you might have to build Bazel yourself to get them.